# NSMutableArray isn't adding all items, just the last one - Iphone / IOS / xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I'm loading icons from an XML file in to an NSMutableArray using the following:

```
NSArray *iconItems = [doc nodesForXPath:kName_icon error:nil];//Root node
    for (CXMLElement *iconItem in iconItems)
    {

        NSArray *iconTempArray = [iconItem elementsForName:kName_url];
        for(CXMLElement *urlTemp in iconTempArray) 
        {
            arryTableAllIcons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [arryTableAllIcons addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlTemp.stringValue]];

            NSLog(@"Icon Found %@",urlTemp.stringValue);

       break;
        }
```

I'm trying to display this in my table through the following: (this is in the `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` )

```
cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableAllIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The count seems to work as I have the correct number of cells, but empty cells in the table and 1 with the last icon found text in

```
The count is just:  `return [arryTableAllIcons count];`
```

And my NSLog brings back the correct text

```
2011-11-07 10:30:23.692 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found guideDogs_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.692 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found WheelchairAssist_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.739 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found walk_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.740 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found DisabledWc_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.741 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found hearingaid_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.741 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found loop_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.742 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found carpark_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.742 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found dropcounter_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.743 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found staff_off.png
2011-11-07 10:30:23.743 Del Search[2791:f203] Icon Found Buggy_off.png
```

So I must just be adding the array wrong!

[image: This is what's returned]

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're declaring the array inside the "For" loop. In this way you're instantiating it every time the cycle repeats

Comment: You little genius, thanks for that. One other thing, now it's working it's displaying 3 blank cells at the bottom? Any idea why

Comment: I'm having a look at your code right now.....Are you NSLogging the return of - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section ?

Comment: Nah I'm NSLoging just after the actual array is built

Comment: I worked it out, as i'm sure you're shocked to learn it was my own stupidity! I was adding to the array when counting the rows!

Answer (score 3):

You're constantly creating new, empty NSMutableArrays

```
    for(CXMLElement *urlTemp in iconTempArray) 
    {
        arryTableAllIcons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arryTableAllIcons addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlTemp.stringValue]];

        NSLog(@"Icon Found %@",urlTemp.stringValue);

   break;
    }
```

Either alloc/init arryTableAllIcons beforehand, or check that it is not nil

```
    for(CXMLElement *urlTemp in iconTempArray) 
    {
        if (!arryTableAllIcons)
            arryTableAllIcons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arryTableAllIcons addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlTemp.stringValue]];

        NSLog(@"Icon Found %@",urlTemp.stringValue);

   break;
    }
```

Also that break statement will exit the enclosing for loop on first pass so I think it should not be there

```
    for(CXMLElement *urlTemp in iconTempArray) 
    {
        if (!arryTableAllIcons)
            arryTableAllIcons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arryTableAllIcons addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlTemp.stringValue]];

        NSLog(@"Icon Found %@",urlTemp.stringValue);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this mate, can you tell me why it's creating 3extra blank cells at the bottom now? It's quite odd

Comment: Difficult to tell with the info you give, try putting a breakpoint at the for loop and see why it's creating extra empty items.

Comment: It's curious, as it's not in the NSLog

Comment: I worked it out, as i'm sure you're shocked to learn it was my own stupidity! I was adding to the array when counting the rows!

Answer (score 1):

At this part of code:

```
for(CXMLElement *urlTemp in iconTempArray) 
{
    arryTableAllIcons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arryTableAllIcons addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlTemp.stringValue]];
    NSLog(@"Icon Found %@",urlTemp.stringValue);
    break;
}
```

You are re-`init`-ing a new `arryTableAllIcons` on every step through the `for` loop.

In addition to creating a memory leak, you are creating lots of new arrays. The last instantiation is the one that has the last item.

Move the alloc-init statement outside of the loop (outside the method entirely, probably, and moved to the class `init`), and make sure you `release` it at some point after you use it.